# Java Pattern.compile expression - "/login?(\\?.+)?"

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to understand the regular expression given below:

```
"/login?(\\?.+)?"
```

I have gone through the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html), but I am not able to clearly understand the purpose of this expression.

I understand that it looks for a string that starts with `/login`, then after that what does the characters `?(\\?.+)?` represent?
Please help me in understanding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `/login` matches the literal characters `/login`
- the `?` makes the `n` optional
- the `(parentheses)` capture the match inside to Group 1
- `/login`
- `\\?` matches a literal `?`. In normal regex it would be `\?`, but in the Java string the backslash has to be escaped with another backslash
- the `.+` matches one or more characters, which can include `spaces and my dog!`

**Sample Matches**

```
/logi
/login
/login?a
/logi?an
/logi?and my dog
```

**General Answers to "What Does this Regex Mean?**

1. You can use a tool such as See [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uM2cZ8) to play with a regex. The right pane explains it token by token.
2. There are several explaining tools based on the same original Perl library, such as [this one](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%2Flogin%3F%28%5C%3F.%2B%29%3F&.submit=Explain!&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode), on which one of the answers is based.
3. The ultimate answer can be found in *Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rd Ed.* and several excellent online tutorials, including the [regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) on this site.

Comment: Thanks zx81 for giving detailed explanation

Comment: It was a pleasure, see you next time! :)

Answer (score 9):

It optionally matches literal text `?some-text-here` after `/login`. Also `/login?` makes last `n` optional:

It matches following inputs:

```
/logi
/login
/logi?something
/login?something
```

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qJ9pC7)

Comment: +1, I would add that it also matches `/login?something and my dog`... :)

Comment: Thanks a lot anubhava, now I understood that `n?` makes `n` as optional. But I have a confusion on why we have double slash for `\\?`, also why we need the brackets `()` here. Also what is the use of the last character `?`. Please help me in understanding.

Comment: The bracket is there to group. It can be used to ask the regex matcher what substring was matched by the subregex inside the bracket.

Comment: 1. In Java we use double escape to escape any regex special symbol and since `?` means 0 or 1 in regex therefore it uses: `\\?` 2. `(\\?.+)` makes it a captured group. 3. `?` after `(\\?.+)` makes literal `?bla-bla` optional.

Comment: Also if you open my suggested demo link there is a very nice **EXPLANATION** of this regex on top-right side.

Answer (score 1):

It matches `/logi` followed by an optional `n` (`?` = the previous element is optional) followed by an optional group (`()` limit a group) starting with `?` (due to the double `\` which escape the `?`) and followed by one or more characters (`.+`, `.` = arbitrary character, `+` = one or more).

Answer (score -1):

`logi` is the static content of the expression.

- `n?` means n occurs never or once
- `()?` means the expression in `()` occurs never or once
- `\\?` means `\` occurs never or once
- `.+` means any character(except new line) occurs once or more